# Error al intentar compilar un ejemplo con Acrobat: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo trabajando en acrobat. Despues de añadir de la libreria de acrobat y al abrir un ejemplo de los que trae la carpeta de acrobat me salta el siguente error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No se pudo recuperar el 
>   generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID
>   {85DE1C45-2C66-101B- B02E-04021C009402} debido al siguiente error:
>   80040154 Clase no registrada  (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

El error salta en la siguente linea :

```
"mApp = new Acrobat.AcroApp();"
```

Estoy trbajando en windows 10 con el visual studio 2017 y la version Acrobat 10 SDK

```
        public BasicIac()
        {
            //
            // Required for Windows Form Designer support
            //
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
        {
            if( disposing )
            {
                if (components != null) 
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 18F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104, 8);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(273, 33);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Sample : BasicIacCS";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
            this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 48);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(441, 137);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "Program is over.";
            // 
            // BasicIac
            // 
            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(476, 202);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
            this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 23);
            this.Name = "BasicIac";
            this.Text = "BasicIacC#";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.BasicIac_Load);
            this.Closed += new System.EventHandler(this.BasicIac_Closed);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() 
        {
            Application.Run(new BasicIac());
        }

        private void StartAcrobatIac()
        {
            //IAC objects
            CAcroPDDoc pdDoc;
            CAcroAVDoc avDoc;

            //constant, hard coding for a pdf to open, it can be changed when needed.
            String szPdfPathConst = Application.StartupPath + "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\..\\TestFiles\\TwoColumnTaggedDoc.pdf";

            //variables
            string szStr;
            string szName;
            int iNum = 0;

            //Initialize Acrobat by creating App object

            mApp = new AcroApp();

            //Show Acrobat
            mApp.Show();

            //set AVDoc object
            avDoc = new AcroAVDoc();

            //open the PDF
            if (avDoc.Open (szPdfPathConst, ""))
            {
                //set the pdDoc object and get some data
                pdDoc  = (CAcroPDDoc)avDoc.GetPDDoc();
                pdDoc = (CAcroPDDoc)avDoc.GetParentPDDoc();
                iNum = pdDoc.GetNumPages ();
                szName = pdDoc.GetFileName();

                //compose a message
                szStr = szName + " has been loaded in Acrobat by the IAC application.\n\n";

                if(iNum >1)
                    szStr += "The PDF document has " + iNum + " pages.\n";
                else
                    szStr += "The PDF document has " + iNum + " page.\n";

                label2.Text = szStr;
            } 
            else 
            {
                label2.Text = "Cannot open " + szPdfPathConst + "\n";
            }
        }

        private void BasicIac_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            StartAcrobatIac();
        }

        private void BasicIac_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if(mApp != null)
            {
                mApp.CloseAllDocs ();
                mApp.Exit ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para que la comunidad entienda mejor su pregunta, debe leer [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego [edit] la pregunta. Puede revisar esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482952/4092887) para orientarse acerca del error que tiene. ¿Su aplicación está configurada en x86 o x64? Saludos.

Comment: Por favor copia el código como texto en la pregunta, de otra manera, las posibilidades de que recibas respuestas son casi nulas. Leer para interpretar y/o replicar tu problema se hace mucho más complejo si el código esta en una imagen

Comment: se trata de un proyecto web ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no es un proyecto web.

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Ahora lo edito, gracias por el consejo

Answer (score 0):

Este mensaje de error sobre librerias COM se relaciona con problemas se permisos, es bastante conocido cuando usas las librerias de Office

[Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154](https://www.technoblogy.net/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046-failed-due-to-the-following-error-80040154/)

Veras que se debe acceder a `DCOM` usando el comando `DCOMCNFG`.
Y luego en el arbol:

```
 Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config
```

Entonces buscas la entrada que hace referencia a los componentes de `Acrobat`, boton derecho seleccionando `propiedades` y de alli validas los permisos

Comment: Buenas, realice lo que me recomendaste y no cambio nada. Al acceder a "propiedades" segui las instrucciones del link que dejaste, pero al querer agregar la cuenta de "Network Service" me dice que no reconoce a dicho objeto. Aun sin poder realizar eso le di permisos a todos los tipos de cuentas en todas las situaciones pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: no intentaste agregar a tu usuario, o quizas Administrator, valida que quien este autenticado en windows tenga permisos a ese componente